# REVISED: Create a car rental system without the need of a trusted third party on blockchain

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, blockchain

I am working on a project which use Blockchain to develop a car rental system, I have very basic knowledge. Basically, I want people to be able to rent their own car to people who want to rent in a short term period, without needing an intermediary, similar to Airbnb.

Basically, there a few questions I want to ask is:

How can I transfer the access to the vehicle between users on a selected date and return the access back to the owner once rental period ends?

How to transfer money from an account once rental period has begun?

Would be difficult to allow either renter or vehicle owner to cancel a rental agreement?

Have multiple vehicles rentable?

I would really appreciate any advice, especially on a coding perspective.

Thank you,

Comment: What you are asking here is too much. You're basically asking us to hold your hand while learning smart contract development. Some random bits of advice: Forget everything you may know about object oriented programming. You don't need a token for this project. Always try to think of ways to attack or cheat your system. An owner is not a car. (have you considered that a person may own multiple cars, or that multiple people may own one car together?)

Comment: You can check an article I wrote some time ago related to this subject. Building an Ethereum-based project that interacts with the physical world is not that straightforward and also requires a lot of security and identification measures. Here's the piece of code I developed, which has not been tested in real life, but hope it helps: https://hackernoon.com/a-smart-contract-for-a-smart-car-db08eda4bb4f

Comment: Also, this other article I wrote about renting smart contracts might help as well: https://hackernoon.com/renting-items-on-the-blockchain-de4e2663dfc6

Comment: Thanks @pabloruiz55, i found your ariticle very interesting. i was actually think when you rent a car to someone, how do ensure they can't access it once the rent period is over? I presumed once it's on the blockchain it's permanent

Comment: @JesseBusman thanks for your comment, i don't want you to hold my hand, just wanted to know if i'm heading the right direction.  Thanks for mentioning about the person owning multiple cars, i did not consider that.